# Changes to database session context persists with pooled connection reuse

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jdbc

In my application, I have a connection pool that I use to obtain connections to Oracle database.

I need to execute statements that call stored procedures that might affect the database session context/variables so that these changes affect only the current use of the connection.

When I close the connection and obtain another connection from the pool, I want it like a new connection/session at which the effect of the procedure doesn't exist. Unfortunately, this doesn't happen.

So I obtain a connection, calls the following procedure:

```
PROCEDURE set_empno (empno NUMBER) IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT('app1_ctx', 'empno', empno);
  END;
```

like this:

```
CALL APP1_CTX_PACKAGE.SET_EMPNO(11)
```

and then I execute this query, which works as expected (returning the value **11**):

```
SELECT "PRICE", "EMPNO" FROM "ORDERS" WHERE empno = SYS_CONTEXT('app1_ctx', 'empno')
```

until now everything looks fine, I close the connection (so it returns to the pool) and call `pool.getConnection` to obtain a connection from the pool (I want it like new without any effects). The problem is if I just after obtaining the connection called:

```
SYS_CONTEXT('app1_ctx', 'empno')
```

I get the value **11** that came from the call before closing the connection. I was expecting to get an error or null since I didn't set the value using this connection.

Is there any way that I can reset the session or the connection to act as a new one without any changes to the context or security context or anything like this

Note that I don't want only to reset the `app1_ctx`, I want to eliminate any changes to the session (I don't know what exactly the user would change in his calls)

Note also that I use this application to access different databases: Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer ..etc

Comment: It depends on Connection pool mechanism you use. Or which JPA implementation you use. For example EclipseLink has support for something like that. On the other side, you do not have any global variable in Java, but you do store it inside Oracle's connection on DB server side. (PS: another "nasty" thing you can do with connection is `ALTER SESSION SET current_schema=...`. Or any other ALTER SESSION statement. There is no way how to reset Oracle's connection into original state.

Comment: I use
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource

Comment: you need to clear the context before reusing the connection in the pool

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I don't understand how can I do so. Can you please add more details?

Comment: how do you close the connection ??

Comment: @RobertoHernandez calling `connection.close()` on the pooled connection object.

Comment: there is a way to remove the properties of the context using `sys.DBMS_SESSION.clear_all_context('parameter_ctx');` If a session is being used as part of a connection pool and the state of its contexts are not reinitialized, this can lead to the behaviour you are mentioning

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle, you will want to call `DBMS_SESSION.RESET_PACKAGE`. Calling that procedure resets the session state of all packages so the session will seem like a new session.

Comment: Great! what about other databases? is there any generic thing I can call on the pooled connection?